# How to have my closeRepository nexus task depend on ALL uploadArchive tasks in gradle?

Tags: gradle

There is one closeRepository task to close the repository on nexus after uploading all artifacts.  I can't seem to do something like this

closeRepository.dependsOn(subprojects)

How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Took me a while but this fixed the issue

```
task uploadArchives << { }

uploadArchives.dependsOn {
    project.subprojects.collectMany { project -> project.tasks }.findAll { task -> task.name.equals("uploadArchives") }
}
```

and I can have closeRepo depend on that one target.